# Searching through a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So I'm trying to search through a model through a form. Basically my end goal is to be able to assign a value a "user" in my User model if this search manages to obtain at least 1 search result, which will only happen if both the Username and Password match on the form for the Organization.

The controller:

```
class OrganizationsController < ApplicationController
    def join
        @organization = Organization.find_by_username_and_password(params[:organization])
    end
end
```

The view:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6">

    <%= form_for(@organization) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :username %>
      <%= f.text_field :username %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <br />
      <%= f.submit "Join!", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I just can't get this to work. What am I doing wrong?
Any help/recommendations would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic finder methods and provide respective attribute value to search.
e.g

```
User.find_by_email_and_password 'test@email','password'
```

we are searching email and pasword,in finder method email come first so first parameter should be email's value and second for password 
interesting you can use any combination of your model's attributes to search

```
User.find_by_password_and_email 'password','test@email'
```

Awesome Rails :)

Comment: Starting in Rails 4, dynamic finder methods will no longer work for more than one field. Try something like this to future proof your app a bit: User.where(:password => 'password', :email => 'test@email').first

Answer (score 1):

The way how you're handling the params is incorrect. Since you're using a form_for, your data in the form would be encapsulated in a hash, namely, params[:organization]

```
organization = params[:organization]
@organization = Organization.find_by_username_and_password(organization[:username], organization[:password])
```

However i'd recommend you to add a debugger before this line of code in your method and experiment yourself!

Comment: I seem to be getting an error `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit further? I.e. what exactly did you try?

Comment: Well I put exactly what you have written in your answer into my join method in OrganizationsController. Other code is as-is. I changed it around as much as I could, but it always comes down to this error. And the error points to `@organization = Organization.find_by_username_and_password(organization[:username], organization[:password])`

Answer (score 0):

According to method name `find_by_username_and_password`, you have to pass two parameters:

```
 Organization.find_by_username_and_password('username', 'password')
```